# tcl regexp name validation

Tags: regex, tcl

I need to validate a name in tcl, it can be:

Letters (upper and lower case)

Numbers

Any of these symbols :
"_"    underscore
 "-"   dash 
"/"    slash

Comment: What were you able to come up with on your own?

Comment: The regexp syntax used in Tcl is [extensively documented](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm). Don't also miss [this one](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: ehh, you know that there is (computer) language to describe what you did? It is called regexp. Some Tip: All lower characters : `[a-z]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
regexp {^[\w/-]+$} $string
```

Comment: You wouldn't need to escape the slash.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers can solve the problem, here an answer how you could write it yourself:

- The string should only contain the defined characters:
  The entire string have to be matched, so add constraints: `^` at the beginning (marks the beginning of the string) and `$` at the end.
- The string should contain of one or more of some characters:
  `[a-z]+` means one or more characters in the range (inclusive) from a to z.
- Add some more possible characters: `^[a-zA-Z_0-9/-]+$`
  (Note that `-` is at the end, otherwise it defines a range)

And voila. Your regexp.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\w-\/]+$/
```

`\w` is for letters, numbers and underscore. [Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Doesn't work in Tcl (where `/` isn't a special character). Read the _whole_ question.

Comment: What doesn't work? Using the `//` as delimiters? It's just a manner of writing a regex. I dare hope the OP's done a little research and at least knows what delimiters to use in whatever flavor he's using. Sorry if I offended you. Can't help it, I'm an optimist.